# Spritesheet with mask or separate image files?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I'm making an animation of a 2D character that can walk, run, jump, bend,...

Would it be better to load one big 'spritesheet' with all the animations and just use a mask, or would loading separate files (walk, run,...) be better because you're not using a mask on such a big image every frame?

I'm not using the Stage3D features with a framework like Starling because I think the normal flash display API is fast enough and has much less bugs than the relatively new GPU frameworks.

Comment: Have you tried using different layers/frames of a new symbol? Whenever I need simple character animations I'll use the top level of the symbol to store left facing sprites in frame 1, right facing sprites in frame 2, within those sprites will be another few frames showing the walking/running animations etc. Basically symbols within symbols (kinda like a multi-dimensional array).

Comment: I'm not using the timeline in Flash Professional, I'm loading the 'frames' from a png file.

Comment: I think using a single sprite sheet (a single bitmap) and a mask (array of rectangles) will be better than using separate pictures, if your animation would have variable sizes of rectangles (width and height), also if your character would be just one, this will cause less overhead in operations than maintaining a set of different bitmaps and doing tricks with them. Still, you can always split your sprite sheet into array of bitmaps if you would like to.

Comment: this masking thing you are referring to is called blitting (just in case other people dont know). Here is a simple tutorial on it: http://www.8bitrocket.com/2010/03/03/tutorial-as3-how-to-blit-an-animation-from-a-tile-sheet-embedded-at-compile-time/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blitting just the character (using `lock(),copyPixels(),unlock()`) works pretty well.

```
private function updatePixels():void{
    //update sprite sheet copy position based on the frame placements ons prite sheet
    position.x = spriteSourceData[currentFrame].x + offset.x;
    position.y = spriteSourceData[currentFrame].y + offset.y; 
    //draw into the bitmap displayed
    displayData.lock();
    displayData.fillRect(displayData.rect, 0x00FFFFFF);//clear
    displayData.copyPixels(sourceData, spriteData[currentFrame], position);//copy new frame pixels
    displayData.unlock();
}
//a bit about vars:
position:Point
spriteSourceData:Vector.<Rectangle> - from parsed Texture Packer data
offset:Point - front view and side view animations weren't always centred, so an offset was needed
displayData:BitmapData - pluging into a Bitmap object displayed
sourceData:BitmapData - the large sprite sheet
currentFrame:int - image index on the sprite sheet
```

I've done this on an older project writing a custom class loosely following what I've learned from Lee Brimelow's tutorial series [Sprite Sheets and Blitting](http://gotoandlearn.com/) ([Part 1](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=140),[Part 2](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=141), [Part 3](http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=142))

[image: blitting and spritesheets]

In short, you'd use two BitmapData objects:

1. a large sprite sheet
2. a small image to display just the character (size of the largest character bounding box) to copy pixels into

In my project I had a character with front and side animations and for the sides I've used one set of animations and used the [Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html) class to flip(scale and translate) the side animation accordingly. I've used [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to export the image sequence as a sprite sheet and the frame data as well as a JSON object. There is native JSON support now, so that's handy. Texture Packer isn't free but it's really worth the money (affordable, fast and does the job perfectly). I haven't used Flash CS6 yet but I imagine it's also possible to import your image sequence and export a spritesheet with the new feature.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the rule "the simpler the display list the better the performance" generally applies. Which means you should use the most specific display object that will do the job (don't use a Sprite when a Shape would be sufficient or favor Bitmaps over vectors where it makes sense).

The most extreme version of this is to only have one Bitmap display object on the stage and use copyPixels to draw all game objects into it every time you want to update the screen. It doesn't really matter what the source in the copyPixel call is, it could either be a large BitmapData acting as a sprite sheet or a small BitmapData objects representing a single frame in an animation. This method is really fast and you could easily have many hundreds of objects on screen at the same time. But using copyPixels means you can't scale or rotate a game object, so for those cases you would have to fall back to the much slower draw() method. Of course this single Bitmap method is not suitable for games where you need to attach mouse events to specfic objects in the game, but works well for shoot'em ups or platform games.

**To answer your question**, I think you will get better performance by using a single Bitmap display object to represent the player and a collection of BitmapData objects for all the animation frames. Then you can just change the Bitmap's bitmapData property to the frame you want to display. You can still load a large spritesheet png and then plit it up into a series of BitmapData objects during the initialization of the game.